# Overwriting Parquet File in Bluemix Object Storage with Apache Spark Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, ibm-cloud, parquet, object-storage

I'm running a Spark Notebook to save a DataFrame as a Parquet File in the Bluemix Object Storage.

I want to overwrite the Parquet File, when rerunning the Notebook. But actually it's just appending the data.

Below a sample of the iPython Code:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table")
df.write.parquet("swift://my-container.spark/simdata.parquet", mode="overwrite")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the python guy,but [SaveMode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode.html) work for dataframe like this

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("swift://my-container.spark/simdata.parquet")
```

Comment: I tried following 
`df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("swift://my-container.spark/simdata.parquet")`
as described here [Spark SQL Save Modes](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#save-modes)
But it's still appending  :/

Comment: can u go ur 4040 port and see what jobs are running

Comment: i meant is there any possibility in ur code tht first write the data thn append it.

Comment: I've reviewed the code, it's just this one very line, where I write the data

Answer (score 0):

I think the blockstorage replace only the 'simdata.parquet' the 'PART-0000*' remains cuz was 'simdata.parquet' with the 'UUID' of app-id, when you try to read, the DF read all files with the  'simdata.parquet*'